# Trigger on Account to create case when account customfield is of type Multiselect picklist is updated

Tags: apex, after-trigger, bulkification

I'm having plan__c field on account object.whenever its is updated I want the new values of plan__c is the subject of a case and new case to be created if new values and old values match no case is created.
Ex: Plan__c consists of x,y values in Old map,X,y,z,A in a new map I want z and A to be created as subject of case separating by';'

Can anyone help me with code I have written a code but it handles only single record.How to Bulkify this

```
trigger AccountCase on Account (after update) {
    List<Account> acc=new list<Account>();
    List <case> casestocreate=new list<case>();
    Id rtype=[select Id, name from RecordType where name ='Customer Training' and SObjectType='Case' limit 1].Id;

    if(Trigger.Isupdate){
        for(Account acc: trigger.new){
            Case c=new case();
            Account oldacc=Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);
            String oldrateplan=oldacc.Rate_Plan_type__c;
            String newrateplan=acc.Rate_Plan_type__c;

            if(oldrateplan!=newrateplan ){
                String subject=oldrateplan.difference(newrateplan);
                c.Subject=subject;
                c.AccountId=acc.id;
                c.RecordTypeId='0126F000000upTVQAY';
                casestocreate.add(c);
            }
        }      
        try{
            insert casestocreate;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Could not insert case-----'+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MultiSelect Picklist are separated by semi-colons, we can split on this and make Sets to do comparisons and remove common elements leaving only new values to create the subject.

```
if(Trigger.Isupdate)
{
    for(Account acc: trigger.new)
    {
        Case c=new case();

        Account oldacc=Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);

        //Since MultiSelect Picklist are separated by semi-colons, we can split on
        //this and make Sets to do comparisons and remove common elements
        //leaving only new values to create the subject
        Set<String> oldVals = new Set<String>(oldacc.Rate_Plan_type__c.split(';'));
        Set<String> newVals = new Set<String>(acc.Rate_Plan_type__c.split(';'));

        if(newVals.removeAll(oldVals))
        {
            //Use String.join() to create string for Subject
            String subject=String.join(new List<String>(newVals), ';');
            c.Subject=subject;
            c.AccountId=acc.id;
            c.RecordTypeId='0126F000000upTVQAY';
            casestocreate.add(c);
        }

    }      
    try{
        insert casestocreate;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Could not insert case-----'+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice; N.B. the `split` assumes the source value is never null; OP will need to consider that;

Comment: Fair point @cropredy